# How to compare api response with Database query result in Robot Framework

Tags: python, database, api, robotframework

I have a Test Case where i have to compare Rest API response with DB result.
Steps i have automated are -
1. POST a request
2. Get the API response
3. Compare with DB result

After posting a request to API, when i try to evaluate it, i am getting below error -

```
failed: TypeError: Expression must be string, got dictionary.
```

```
create session  session  ${apiurl}  disable_warnings=1
    &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json  x-api-key=${api_token_key}
    ${api_response}=    post request  session    ${emp_id}/${module_name}  data=${request_body}
    ...  headers=${headers}
${response_list}=  evaluate  ${api_response.json()}
log to console  ${response_list}
```

Getting above error.

I am expecting below API response to be compared with the DB result.

```
 "page": {
    "size": 5,
    "totalElements": 278,
    "totalPages": 56,
    "number": 0
  },
  "embedded": {
    "emp": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "bookid": 2,
        "batchid": "2018-aaa",
        "title": "ash",
        "sub1": 10,
        "sub2": 11,
        "sub failed": {
          "total": {
            "value": 50,
            "subject": "sub6",
            "filter": "[{"field":"1","exclusive":false,"operator":"IN","value":"2018-aaa"}]"
          }
        },
        "sports": {
          "total": {
            "value": 12,
            "subject": "PE",
            "filter": "[{"field":"1","exclusive":false,"operator":"IN","value":"2018-aaa"}]"
          }
        },
        "count": 222,
        "count1": 333,
        "improved": 0,
        "last": "2019-08-12",
        "isstudent": true
      },
```

How to compare the above API response with DB result

Comment: what's is your Json body format type while u posting to the server? string or dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary is posted to Server

Answer (score 2):

just change your param `data` to `json` because if you use `data` it's for only `Json string` type.

```
create session  session  ${apiurl}  disable_warnings=1
    &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json  x-api-key=${api_token_key}
    ${api_response}=    post request  session    ${emp_id}/${module_name}  json=${request_body}
    ...  headers=${headers}
${response_list}=  evaluate  ${api_response.json()}
log to console  ${response_list}
```

Comment: But it still returns json and how to loop over the json response and compare with DB result

Comment: I think it's another question

Comment: @vectyvec how do u try to compare the result to db? you should share your code and your error